# Why is numerical differentiation of neural network has a scaling of big O(w^2)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In the book **Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning(Bishop)** chapter 5.3.3, it talks about the problem of numerical differentiation compared to backpropagation. While simple forward and back propagation is each O(w) operation, numerical differentiation results in $O(w^2)$. I don't understand why this would result in $O(w^2)$. Don't we just find $E_{n}(w_{ji}+e)$ and $E_{n}(w_{ji}-e)$? how does this results in $O(w^2)$? can someone please give me an explanation? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you precise what $w$ represents here?

Comment: $w$ is the weight parameter in neural network